# Что такое активность-хост?

Tags: java, android, activity, хост

В книге "Android программирование для профессионалов" столкнулся с таким понятием как активность-хост. Как я понял из контекста, активность-хост - это активность, которая взаимодействует с фрагментом. 
Правильно ли я понял значение этого понятия?

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, страницу книги, где вам это встретилось.

Comment: Нашел первое упоминание в книге. Да, Вы правильно в целом поняли. Единственное уточнение - Активность-хост может не взаимодействовать с фрагментом напрямую, но фрагмент находится в ней. (У Вас может быть фрагмент внутри фрагмента, тогда будут и Активность-хост и Фрагмент-хост)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, спасибо!

Comment: @pavlofff, благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае активность-хост, это такая активность, которая сама не отображает контент или интерфейс, а только управляет фрагментами (создает их, меняет на нужный и т.п.), контент же или интерфейсы отображаются уже в фрагментах.

По аналогии с сервером, а фрагменты - это сайты.